# Centre data based on skewed week numbers

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have a problem that I can do manually in 2 minutes in excel, but I need to incorporate it into a function in R.

Original dataset:

```
df <- data.frame(week=c(1:52), values=c(77, 87, 74, 72, 62, 79, 85, 114,    170,    178,
                                    141,    143,    118,    124,    112,    92, 76, 64, 62, 
                                    75, 63, 60, 76, 69, 60, 46, 42, 34, 23, 21, 19, 
                                    23, 23, 26, 24, 18, 21, 21, 25, 38, 21, 17, 20, 16, 
                                    9,  6,  6,  17, 36, 52, 65, 79))
```

Looks like this:

```
    week values
1    1     77
2    2     87
3    3     74
4    4     72
5    5     62
6    6     79
```

Problem: I have a vector of values based on weeks of the year (I have made up a smaller dataset for the example dataset). I need to be able to assign the highest value a value of 0, then give every value either side of that a number, depending on how many weeks away from the peak it is. The values either side of the peak may fluctuate, so I can’t just use a ranking and assign numbers using that, it has to be ranked by week.

The main problem I have is that I have my weeks are numbered based on our calendar year, but the peak value appears in week 10, so I end up with values from 1 to 42 for above week 10, and -1 to -9 below week 10.

```
df_final <- data.frame(week=c(37,   38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
                          47,   48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  
                          7,    8,  9,  10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 
                          19,   20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
                          31,   32, 33, 34, 35, 36),

            values=c(21,    21, 25, 38, 21, 17, 20, 16, 9,  6,  6,  17, 36, 
                      52,   65, 79, 77, 87, 74, 72, 62, 79, 85, 114,    170,    178,    
                      141,  143,    118,    124,    112,    92, 76, 64, 62, 75, 63, 60,
                      76,   69, 60, 46, 42, 34, 23, 21, 19, 23, 23, 26, 24, 18),

            centred = c(-25, -24,-23,-22,-21,-20,-19,-18,-17,-16,-15,-14,-13,
                        -12,-11,-10,-9,-8,  -7, -6, -5, -4,-3,  -2, -1, 0,  1,  
                        2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,  11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 
                        16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26))
```

My final dataset should look something like this (head):

```
  week values centred
1   37     21     -25
2   38     21     -24
3   39     25     -23
4   40     38     -22
5   41     21     -21
6   42     17     -20
```

I am completely stumped on how to do this.

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a long list and you are just locating a single max value in the list then this may work:

```
mymax<-which.max(df$values)
len<-length(df$week)
df_fin<-cbind(df, centered= (-mymax+1):(-mymax+len))
```

The newly added column "centered" will have your desired ranking.  This does not recycle the weeks as your df_final shows, which is possible with the addition of an if statement.

Now if you need to recycle then this segment may work for you:

```
mymax<-which.max(df$values)
df2<-rbind(df, df)
if(mymax<26){
  mid=52+mymax
  dff<-df2[(mid-25):(mid+26),]
}else{
  mid=mymax
  dff<-df2[(mid-25):(mid+26),]
}
dff<-cbind(dff, centred=-25:26)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. It's the If statement that I'm having problems with. I originally managed to get as far as your solution using an if statement, but it's how to recycle the numbers that's stumping me. So at the moment my numbers run from -9 through to 42, when I want them to run from -25 to 26.